# Connecting flight

Tags: air-travel, qatar, doha

It's my first two-step flight and I have a question.
My flight is from Warsaw to Indonesia, Denpasar with a change in Doha. Both flights take place on the Qatar Airwaves line. I have an hour and a half to change in Doha, what is the situation with my luggage? Will the carrier carry the luggage himself or do I have to pick up the luggage myself and re-send it?

Comment: Is the flight all 1 booking or did you book each leg separately?

Comment: Everything in one booking, also including flight back from Denpasar to Warsaw and another transit in Doha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If both legs of your flight are under one PNR then you will not have to pick up the luggage at Doha. The baggage will be transferred by the airline to Indonesia directly in that case.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, on connecting flights your baggage is checked all the way to the end of the journey.

In my experience, some carriers do give you the option of collecting your luggage at each stop too, but this is optional.

If you're still unsure, you can always double check with the check in desk.

Comment: For those reading this is a different context, the biggest exception is transit in the US when arriving from abroad (except airports with pre-clearance). Of course “connecting” means on the same ticket/booking/PNR.